# wordpress picking up styles that does not exist

Tags: css, wordpress

i am facing a very weird issue, i was working on a wordpress site on version 4.9.1 i included some css which the client then told to remove i have removed the css but that css is still loading up on the website although it does not exist

here is the screenshot!
[image]

i have checked this file a dozen times, i have cleared the browser cache ,tried hard refreshing it, opened it in incognito mode, everything still it loads up , is there something about this scenario i don't know?

the domain is [Website link](http://smirksbrand.com/)

Comment: Just to confirm, you're saying the styling remains even when you remove it from the file?

Comment: exactly! thats the problem

Comment: Have you definitely removed it from style.min.css, not style.css?

Comment: already did that although there is one scenario when i refresh on regular tab of browser it doesnt show up but when i open it in icognito tab which always fetches the fresh styles etc it indeed shows up

Comment: do you want to remove the whole style.min.css from website or just a part of the css code inside that file?

Comment: i just want to remove the code,which i already did actually but it still loads up

Comment: try changing the version of the style.css

Comment: what do you mean by version?

Comment: so when you edit the file directly through ftp and save it on ftp, is it successfully saved with correct timestamp? or is it being overridden later by some script?

Comment: i actually edited it using wp backend not ftp, about the script i dont think that this is a script problem because it shows exactly the same styles as there were before.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: if included in header. try changing and uploading `<link style ........ href="...../style.css?v=1"... />`

Comment: nops it doesnt work on incognito

Comment: @uneebmeer did u try changing the version and using it? is ur style.css auto loaded?

Comment: i am trying it is using wp_head in the header file i opened funtions.php but i cannot find a method named wp_head()

Comment: are u using anything like cloudflare

Comment: you edited using wp backend, through theme - editor? you need to check if the file is being updated / saved...

Comment: by the look of it, it is updated like i opened the file again in incognito also.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the CSS file included: http://smirksbrand.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/assets/css/style.min.css?ver=5.1.4
at the end of it there's still this:

```
.fusion-main-menu > ul > li {
    padding-right: 20px!important;
}
```

that you want to get rid of.

Comment: that is the issue! this was my code but now its removed!, but this is still being loaded. i hav verified a dozen times in the backend it doesn't exist i am sure of it the how wp is getting those styles

Comment: You could have had it in cache, but since I can see it - it surely must be there on the server. I don't know how did you verified it on back-end, by FTP? It is possible that you are connecting to some old copy of this site - other server, other directory not the directory linked to this domain.

Comment: i am using wordpress backend , i verified it by editing appearence-> editor -> Avada(Theme Name) -> assets-> css-> style.min.css!  nops, nothing there

Comment: Personally I'd connect by FTP to your theme directory, took this style.min.css file and got rid of this line that overwrites your edits - for me it would be the fastest approach.

Comment: ya but the client doesn't agree i asked for ftp from the beginning he said its a small issue fix it on the backend, look where it got me :/

Comment: If you cannot find another CSS file on the Wordpress back-end to edit, and you don't have FTP access I think the last resort would the `!important` attribute that you should add to your changes.

Answer (score -1):

Consider removing this from your head tag...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="avada-stylesheet-css" href="http://smirksbrand.com/wp-content/themes/Avada/assets/css/style.min.css?ver=5.1.4" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Isn't this the one that's disturbing you?

**Edit:**

Based on your picture, if you want padding-right to be 45px, put !important to it...

```
.fusion-main-menu>ul>li {
    padding-right: 45px!important;
}
```

This will take precedence over the rogue loading style... Hope it helps...

Comment: yes but its not that simple it also has ton of other styles that are needed because it is the core css file of theme i cant remove that